# Array filter not working on page refresh while using vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have this method (below), which works perfectly when I'm directed from a `<router-link>`.

```
selectedSpaceObj() {
                if (!this.selectedSpace) {
                    return {};
                } else {
                    return this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id === this.selectedSpace);
                }
            }
```

However on refreshing the page, or going to the link directly it doesn't work. I can confirm that `this.selectedSpace` has a value even after the refresh. If I get routed to this page with a param of 1, and have the url `myspaces/1`, I store this value in selectedSpace, however on refresh I get an empty array (or some sort of weird array). But it shouldn't be? Anyone know how to fix this error?

Here is the rest of my code:
**routes.js** contains these two paths:

```
{
    path: '/myspaces',
    name: 'myspaces',
    component: MySpaces
},

{
    path: '/myspaces/:spaceID',
    name: 'returnToSpaces',
    component: MySpaces,
    props: true
}
```

The concept behind it is that I pass spaceID via a `<router-link>`, from 1 page to another. This works. The `spaceID` is passed on correctly.

**Room.vue** - has a router-link to MySpaces.vue

```
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'returnToSpaces', params: { spaceID: spaceID } }">
        <v-btn>
            <h3> go back </h3>
        </v-btn>
    </router-link>
```

When I'm on the `room.vue` and I click on the button, it redirects me to the `myspaces.vue` as the link `myspaces/1` correctly with a spaceID. However If I type `myspaces/1` manually instead of being redirected, it doesn't work. It gives me the error: `Cannot read property 'rooms' of undefined`. This prop is linked to the spaceID which, so most likely when I refresh it, it doesn't link the /1 to the spaceID parameter?

**myspaces.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container>

                    <v-layout>
                        <!-- My spaces -->
                        <v-flex md8 xs12>
                            <v-layout row wrap>
                                <!-- The rooms, allRoomsObj returns all rooms in the space with the id of selectedSpace. -->

                                <v-flex v-for="room in allRoomsObj"
                                        :key="room.id"
                                        xs12
                                        sm6
                                        md6
                                        lg6
                                        :class="{'roomDesktop': !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs, 'roomMobile': $vuetify.breakpoint.xs}"
                                >
                                    <!-- A room -->
                                    <v-card class="card-round">
                                        <!-- Image -->
                                        <v-carousel :cycle="false" hide-delimiters :hide-controls="room.images.length <= 1">
                                            <!--:hide-controls="images.length <= 1"-->
                                            <v-carousel-item v-for="image in room.images" :src="image.src" :key="image.id"></v-carousel-item>
                                        </v-carousel>
                                        <!-- Information -->
                                        <v-card-text primary-title>
                                            <v-layout>
                                                <v-flex xs11>
                                                    <!-- MISSING INFORMATION IN STORE -->
                                                    <h4 class="roomType"> <router-link :to="{ name: 'room', params: { spaceID: selectedSpaceObj[0].id, roomID: room.id  } }">{{ room.type }}</router-link> </h4>
                                                    <h2> {{ room.name }} </h2>
                                                </v-flex>
                                                <v-flex xs1 hidden-sm-and-down>
                                                    <v-btn @click="selectedRoom = room.id"
                                                           :flat="selectedRoom !== room.id"
                                                           :outline="selectedRoom !== room.id"
                                                           fab
                                                           class="selectRoomBtn"
                                                           depressed
                                                    >
                                                    </v-btn>
                                                </v-flex>
                                            </v-layout>
                                        </v-card-text>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-flex>

                        <!-- Sidebar -->
                        <v-flex hidden-sm-and-down sm4 lg4 class="sidebarSticky">
                            <v-layout row wrap>
                                <!--1 room details, selectedRoomObj returns 1 room with id of selectedRoom, that is in the space with id selectedSpace.-->
                                <v-flex v-for="room in selectedRoomObj" :key="room.id">
                                    <v-card class="card-round">
                                        <!-- Show only 1 image -->
                                        <v-card-media v-for="image in room.images.slice(0,1)" :src="image.src" height="200px" :key="image.id">
                                        </v-card-media>

                                        <v-card-text>
                                            <!-- Side bar - room name -->
                                            <h2 class="sidebarRoomName"> {{ room.name }} </h2>
                                            <!-- description -->
                                            <p> {{ room.description }} </p>
                                            <!-- overview button-->
                                            <p> <router-link :to="{ name: 'room', params: { spaceID: selectedSpace, roomID: selectedRoom } }">room overview..</router-link></p>

                                            <!-- styles/pins/moodboard -->

                                        </v-card-text>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-flex>

                    </v-layout>

                </v-container> <!-- End of MAIN CONTENT-->
</template>

<script>
    import { mapState } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: "myspaces",
        props: [
          'spaceID'
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                filterMaxLength: 3,
                selectedSpace: 0,
                selectedRoom: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            // Default selected space (first in json)
            this.selectedSpace = this.spaces[0].id;
            // console.log("spaces " + this.spaces[0].id)

            if (this.spaceID != null) {
                this.selectedSpace = this.spaceID;
            }

            // Default selected room (first in json)
            this.selectedRoom = this.spaces[0].rooms[0].id;

            // If spaceID is received, change the room to the first room in that space.
            if (this.spaceID != null) {
                var backToSpace = this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id == this.spaceID)
                this.selectedRoom = backToSpace[0].rooms[0].id
            }

        },
        computed: {
            // Get 'spaces' from store.
            ...mapState([
                'spaces'
            ]),
            // Grab all the rooms in the selected space.
            allRoomsObj() {
                if (!this.selectedSpaceObj) {
                    return {};
                } else {
                    return this.selectedSpaceObj[0].rooms;
                }
            },
            // Grab the space that with the id that equals to the selectedSpace.
            selectedSpaceObj() {
                if (!this.selectedSpace) {
                    return {};
                } else {
                    return this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id === this.selectedSpace);
                }
            },
            // Grab the room in the selected space, with the room id that equals to selectedRoom.
            selectedRoomObj() {
                if (!this.selectedSpaceObj) {
                    return {};
                } else {
                    return this.selectedSpaceObj[0].rooms.filter(aRoom => aRoom.id === this.selectedRoom);
                }
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Array filter can never return undefined, it would return empty array []. Please make sure if something is making it return undefined.

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha Sorry I mispoke, it returns [], nothing. However when I replace `this.selectedSpace` with an id of a space, it returns an correct object. The weird thing is, when I `console.log(this.selectedSpace)` it has the correct value. When I try to use `this.selectedSpaceObj` in another computed prop I get an error saying that it is undefined.

Comment: You given information is kinda inadequate to find right issue causing it, it would helpful if you tell how are you setting this.selectedSpace, and this.spaces. Where are these values coming from and how are you setting them.

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha Sorry I added all the code.

Comment: How do you get the data from the backend? Is it possible, that your json is not available when the component get's created?

Comment: @ThomasKleßen I've just stored my data in the Store. Its not grabbing it from a DB. So there shouldn't be any issues there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be the type strict comparison inside this code (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) - "puelo"

**change this:**

`this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id === this.selectedSpace)`

**to**

`this.spaces.filter(aSpace => aSpace.id == this.selectedSpace)`